# Unable to setup hex to rgba conversion on gatsby

Tags: gatsby, postcss, rgba

I am trying to convert colors using `postcss-hexrgba`, but it seems that there are problems with my setup. First of all, I have a following code:

`background-color: rgba(theme('colors.grey'), 0.1);`

`theme('colors.black')`  returns a hex value from some library (`#000`).

If I refresh my page, I get:

`` Argument `$color` of `rgba($color, $alpha)` must be a color ``.

This works if I have:

`background-color: rgba(#000, 0.1);`

Now I believe there is something wrong with my setup, but I cannot figure out.

I am using `gatsby` and in my `gatsby-config.js` I have something like this:

```
const pluginHexrgba = require('postcss-hexrgba');
const pluginImport = require('postcss-import');
const pluginMixins = require('postcss-mixins');

<...>

{
  resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-sass',
  options: {
    implementation: sass,
    postCssPlugins: [
      pluginImport(),
      pluginMixins(),
      pluginNested(),
      pluginVars(),
      pluginHexrgba(),
      pluginInternalUi(),
      pluginAutoprefixer(),
      pluginOptimisations(),
      pluginStats(),
      ].filter(Boolean),
    },
},
```

I am sure, that my `theme()` function returns correct hex values, as i am able to use this if not `rgba` case, for example:

`background-color: theme('colors.orange');`

Can someone help me out, it has been hours and I am out of Google results.

Comment: Where does the theme come from?

Comment: @ksav Internal library, exposed via `node_modules` as a package.

Comment: Any more info on that?